# explanation for "properties" object in the response of neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

using:

- node.js - version 8.0.0
- [neo4j-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver): 1.3.0
- neo4j database: community edition, version: 3.2.0

i am running a cypher (not important what exactly is the cypher) and getting back a result.

after parsing the result using the follwing code:

```
result.records[0].get('instanceStock').properties
```

i am getting the following json:

```
{  
   "quantity":{  
      "low":10,
      "high":0
   }
}
```

the value 10 is the correct one which actually reside inside the db.

---

1. what is the meaning of the "low" and "high" properties?
2. why the  correct answer reside inside the "low" property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with how 64bit integers are handled in JS. More explanation here :

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/tree/ad0317a675d50443ca97f157f119957354b74ae3#numbers-and-the-integer-type